Can't copy certain files to Linux share from Windows
I am having trouble copying file created by a specific machine to my Linux share from any of my Windows computer. I have a Linux machine that I have setup with some hot folders monitored by incron. The folders work fine, the scripts I have pointed at each folder run happily when copying any file locally. I go to one of the Windows computers on my network, the computer will happily copy some files but not others. On the files it doesn't copy, it says the file already exists and if I want to replace it. If I say "skip" it finishes the copy and I end up with a null copy of the file in my output folder. If I say "replace" it says I need permission to perform this action. The file is housed on an NAS. If I copy the file to a flash drive before the Linux share, it works fine, but if I copy locally otherwise (like to the desktop) it still doesn't work. The files that have problems have the common denominator of being created on our one Mac.
I think the problem is rooted somewhere in the meta data of the file, but I don't know which aspects need to be fixed. I've tried changing the group owner and read/write permissions to match other files that have worked. Making a new pdf from a "non-working" pdf also allows it to be copied to the Linux share.
As mentioned before copying from the NAS to the hot folder on the Linux machine works fine. I've also tried hosting the hot folder on the NAS which the copy goes through, but incron doesn't see the change so doesn't run the script unless the NAS is mounted through the Linux share.
I have tested the filenames, unless the Mac is adding invisible zero width characters, removing spaces or special characters (even if they're allowed in Windows filenames) has no effect.
Versions:
Linux machine - Linux Mint Debian Edition 5
Windows version - 10 and 11
Mac OS version - 10.11.6 (El Capitan), connected to NAS using AFP
NAS - Samba version 4.7.0
Linux Samba - 4.13.13-Debian

I presume you’re using Samba and SMB, if so, what version. Provide this information as an edit to your question

Have you already checked filenames, such as for special characters or, worse, spaces?

Markdown formatting goes a long way in information presentation... markdown makes things clearer and easier to digest
